# Is "in" redundant in the phrase "in during"?

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> The number of civilian security personnel deaths from Islamist terrorism in India, excluding Jammu and Kashmir, was 926 in during 2000 to 2018.

I don't see any difference if I used just "during" in place of "in during" in the sentence. Am I right in thinking so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct - `in` is redundant here, but there is also something else wrong/missing in the first half. I assume that something like `killed` was in the original, but this smells like a badly edited (reduced) piece of prose, so this sort of error is quite common in newsprint.

Massive guess, but I suspect this originally said: `... in the period from 2000 to 2018`

Answer (score 0):

I see in *[The Hindu](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/indias-perilous-obsession-with-pakistan/article26925287.ece)*:

> In the period 2000-2019, 22,577 civilians and 7,080 security personnel were killed in terrorism-related violence in Pakistan (the number of civilian/security personnel deaths from Islamist terrorism in India, excluding Jammu and Kashmir, **was 926 in during 2000-2018**).

To me this looks like a simple sub-editing error: correct versions would be **in 2000-2018**, **during 2000-2018** or (best in my opinion) **in the period 2000-2018**.